# What is the best way to attach a running total to selected row data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Created at    | Amount  | Register Name
--------------+---------+-----------------
01/01/2019... | -150.01 | Front
01/01/2019... |   38.10 | Back
```

What is the best way to attach an ascending-by-date running total to each record which applies only to the register name the record has? I can do this in Ruby, but doing it in the database will be much faster as it is a web application.

The application is a Rails application running Postgres 10, although the answer can be Rails-agnostic of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the aggregate `sum()` as a window function, e.g.:

```
with my_table (created_at, amount, register_name) as (
values
    ('2019-01-01', -150.01, 'Front'),
    ('2019-01-01',   38.10, 'Back'),
    ('2019-01-02', -150.01, 'Front'),
    ('2019-01-02',   38.10, 'Back')
)

select 
    created_at, amount, register_name,
    sum(amount) over (partition by register_name order by created_at)
from my_table
order by created_at, register_name;

 created_at | amount  | register_name |   sum   
------------+---------+---------------+---------
 2019-01-01 |   38.10 | Back          |   38.10
 2019-01-01 | -150.01 | Front         | -150.01
 2019-01-02 |   38.10 | Back          |   76.20
 2019-01-02 | -150.01 | Front         | -300.02
(4 rows)
```

Comment: You could say `Model.select('models.*, sum(amount) over (...) as running_total')` and then  call `running_total` on the results to integrate this with Rails.

Comment: Thank you both, I upvoted both answers as they both helped me. I will use this as a launching pad to learn more about the partition function. Thanks again!